# OpenTelemetry configuration without AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk

Tags: java, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I need to configure OpenTelemetry without using AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.
How can I achieve the same functionality of the code below:

```
 OpenTelemetry openTelemetry = AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                        .addPropertiesCustomizer(x -> telemetryProperties)
                        .addResourceCustomizer(this::customizeResource)
                        .setServiceClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
                        .setResultAsGlobal(false)
                        .registerShutdownHook(false)
                        .build()
                        .getOpenTelemetrySdk();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk` is just a wrapper around the builder classes for the SDK and its component pieces. You can use those builder classes directly.

You can find the documentation for this type of setup here: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#sdk-configuration

```
// Create an instance of the OpenTelemetrySdk class.
OpenTelemetrySdk openTelemetrySdk = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
    .setTracerProvider(
        SdkTracerProvider.builder()
            // Customize the resource if desired.
            .setResource(Resource.create()
                .merge(this.customizeResource(Resource.getDefault()))
            )
            .build()
    )
    .build();

// Create an instance of the OpenTelemetry interface using the OpenTelemetrySdk.
OpenTelemetry openTelemetry = openTelemetrySdk.getOpenTelemetry();
```